# Comparing DataFrame columns with another list and change

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, compare

Good Day,

I have a Pandas DataFrame with a column 'Cityname' and another list of 'BigCities'
For each row in the column 'Cityname' I would like to exchange the Cityname 
when the city is in the list of 'BigCities' to 1 or if not 0.

Can anyone help with that. I Have problems when it comes to two lists when comparing.

Thank you kindly.

Regards

Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check membership by list `BigCities` with [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and then cast to integers:

```
df['Cityname'] = df['Cityname'].isin(BigCities).astype(int)
```

Or use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['Cityname'] = np.where(df['Cityname'].isin(BigCities), 1, 0)
```